# Why do I have two postman icons

Tags: unity, 20.10, software-uninstall

I installed postman using a download from the website. Now I have an issue with two postman entries in my app menu. (Don't know the proper name.)

I can't get a screenshot of the app menu, but it has the one I want, which has a white flying guy, and then the one I don't want, which has a guy slightly colored.

So I went into the software app to uninstall the other one. I did a search on postman and here's what I found.

[image]

So the other one doesn't seem to exist here.

When I run `grep -iR "Postman" /usr/share/applications/ ~/.local/share/applications/` I get

```
thomas@bravos:~$ grep -iR "Postman" /usr/share/applications/ ~/.local/share/applications/
/home/thomas/.local/share/applications/chrome-fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop-Default.desktop:Name=Postman
thomas@bravos:~$
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: What is the output of `grep -iR "Postman" /usr/share/applications/ ~/.local/share/applications/`?

Comment: @yfluK Answered by editing the question.

Comment: Postman seems to be installed as a Chrome app as well in your system. Open Chrome/Chromium, type `chrome://apps` in URL bar and hit Enter. Do you see Postman there?

Comment: @yfluK that was it. Please post as answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the output of `grep -iR "Postman" /usr/share/applications/ ~/.local/share/applications/`, Postman seems to be installed as a Chrome/Chromium app. To uninstall that app, either go to `chrome://apps` or just delete the file you got after `grep`ing.